# I get socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known when I run it on Linux but not on MAC os x

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests

I am using python 3.5.4, requests 2.21.0, urllib3 1.24.1 and sockets 1.0.0

When I run the following code on my Mac (OS Mojave) it connects to the website correctly and returns the html for me to scrape and analyze, however, when I tried this on linux VM Ware because out client does not have a MAC, I receive a socket error.

```
quote_page = "http://stats.ncaa.org/teams/312381"
hdr = {
    'Temp': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
session = requests.Session()
req = session.get(quote_page, headers=hdr)
```

Error: 
`socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

I am able to recreate the error on my MAC when I try connecting via direct low level sockets.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = ("http://stats.ncaa.org/teams/312381", 80)
s.connect(server)
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n")
print(s.recv(4096))
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, and why it works on OS X but not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: Issue was I was getting a url from a webpage, and the format of the webpage changed depending on which OS I was using. Meaning I got a bad url from the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're including the string `http://` and the URL path (`/teams/312381`) in the host name portion of the address you're connecting to. Omit that, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

just check the hostname:

```
scutil --get HostName
```

it should be `localhost`

otherwise set it to `localhost` by running command

```
scutil --set HostName localhost
```